# Everytime I click preview in GTM I receive a Validate Container popup and Javascript Compiler error?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have found cookie script from a website https://allies4me.com/analytics/google-tag-manager-set-cookies/#comments as I am completely new to Google tag manager and not very html savvy.

I followed all instructions from the website above but when I come to click on Preview in GTM it pops up with Validate Container and the following errors:

Cookie Setter Error at line 3, character 100: Parse error.'}' expected
Here is the code:

```
<script>
function setPersistentCookie(name, value, expires) {
 var cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/; domain=." + 
location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, "");</pre>
if (typeof expires !== "undefined") {
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime() + expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
cookie += "; expires=" + now.toUTCString();
}

document.cookie = cookie;
}

function setSessionCookie(name, value) {
var cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/; domain=." + 
location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, "");

document.cookie = cookie;
}

function getCookie(name) {
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";"),
toReturn;

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
if (cookie.indexOf(name + "=") === 0) {
toReturn = cookie.substring((name + "=").length, cookie.length);
}
}

return toReturn;
}
</script>
```

Paid Customer Error at line 3, character 27: Parse error. primary expression expected

```
<script>
var cookieName = "PaidCustomer"; 
var cookieValue = "true";</pre>
setPersistentCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, 365); // set for 1 year
</script>
```

Page View Count Error at line 3, character 49: Parse error.'}' expected

```
<script>
(function() {
 var pageviewCount = getCookie("pageviewCount");</pre>
if (typeof pageviewCount === "undefined") {
pageviewCount = 1;
} else {
pageviewCount++;
}</pre>
setPersistentCookie("pageviewCount", pageviewCount, 30);

})();
</script>
```

Can someone please show me what is wrong? As I have no idea.

Comment: Remove the </pre> - that's HTML, presumably from when you copied the code (since the pre-tag displays unformatted text in a monospace font is often used for code displays). You cannot mix JS and HTML that way (and you don't want to).

Comment: Hi Eike, thankyou so much I wouldn't have found that without some help. It seems to be previewing fine now, thankyou again.